# Show list nested in another list via ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Basically I have an array of districts  that are shown via ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="district in districts | filter:search:startsWith" class="district">

      <h4 class="district-name">{{ district.district }}</h4>
```

Here is an array:

```
var districtsArrayNotSorted = [
    {district:'Alpha district',link:'#',cities:['Zumbida','Kappa','Numba']},
    {district:'Beta district',link:'#',cities:['Jordda','Mamba','Nemessis']},
    {district:'Berta district',link:'#',cities:['Rumba','Samba','Chacha']},
    {district:'Gamma district',link:'#',cities:['Zapdos','Pikachu']}
];
var districtsArray = districtsArrayNotSorted.sort(function(a,b){
    var distrA = a.district.toLowerCase(), distrB = b.district.toLowerCase();
    if ( distrA > distrB) return 1
});
```

District array has another arrays (with cities of each district) inside.

I'm trying to show than cities (nested in the nested arrays) in `.district` blocks.

Here is [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/MvhXFGGOlLXqapJatfff?p=preview)

Do you have any ideas how is possible to reach that cities to show them?

Comment: Just add an other ng-repeat inside, iterating `city in district.cities`?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/YvM7nDRMBv4cYylZ8nJQ?p=preview

Comment: I think I finally have to sleep a little bit to not bother people with stupid questions.... Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you can do smt like this:

```
 <div class="container">

        <input id="q" type="text" ng-model="search " />

        <div ng-repeat="district in districts | filter:search:startsWith" class="district">

          <h4 class="district-name">{{ district.district }}</h4>
          <a href="{{ district.link }}">Some info</a>

          <ul class="district-cities">

            <li ng-repeat="city in district.cities">
              {{city}}
            </li>

          </ul>


        </div>

    </div>
```

plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/D2ng7Y?p=preview)